# disable or hide listbox by dropdown selection in C#

Tags: c#, sql

HELLO

i have one dropdown box and one listbox ,

my dropdown box values is

```
1-ALL
2-CUSTOM
```

my listbox values is retrieved from sql database

- email addresses

what i want to do is  if i select ALL from the dropdown box , it will disable or hide the list box in the web page. , if i choose "CUSTOM" it will enable it again.

i tried this code, but it doesn't work

```
if (DropDownList1.Text == "CUSTOM")
    {
        ListBox1.Visible = true;
    }
```

note : i put visible = false in the properties of the listbox1

where is the problem exactly ? and where should i put this condition on the .cs page ?

Comment: no web form inside visual web developer studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an event to the dropdown box, so that your code is executed when the event fires.  If you are using the designer, select the dropdown then above where the properties are there should be a little lightning symbol.  Click on that and you will see all the events that the dropdown can fire.  In there look for `SelectedIndexChanged`.  Double click in there and it will create some code for you, which will look something like:

```
protected void mycombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Put your code in that section.

Comment: I tried that protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (DropDownList1.Text == "CUSTOM")
        {
            ListBox1.Visible = true;
        }

    
    } but also did n't work

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear that you were using webforms.  You will also need to set the dropdownlist AutoPostBack property to true, so that when you change the item, it will post back to the server and then your code will be run.

Comment: well , there is a refreshing now each time i choose "ALL" or "CUSTOM" but the status of the listbox doesn't changed , it stills hidden

Comment: OK, well DropDownList1.Text will check the Value property of the <asp:ListItem>  if you want to check the Text property, then you will need to do:  if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "CUSTOM")

Comment: You could also use DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "CUSTOM"

Comment: Not if the list item was created as <asp:ListItem Text="CUSTOM" Value="1"></asp:ListItem> - DropDownList1.SelectedValue would contain "1"

Comment: here is my dropbox code if it helps <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="Page_Load">
                        <asp:ListItem>ALL</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>CUSTOM</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: onselectedindexchanged="Page_Load" is your problem - this should be onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:
If the text in the dropdown is CUSTOM then use this

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "CUSTOM")
        {
            ListBox1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

You will also need to set the AutoPostBack="true" on the DropDownList1.

Comment: i am sorry i didn't work , i also tried to change it to "1-CUSTOM" , also did n't work , because 0-ALL 1-CUSTOM, i want to remind that i am using webforms not winforms , also i set the autopostback = "true" and tested the page on IE and firefox to make sure there is no problem with browser , same nothing happens but refreshing each time i select either ALL or CUSTOM, Appreciate your help :)